# Nesting variable reference in github action workflows

Tags: github, github-actions

Here is my requirement. I have separate GitHub secrets created for each environment.

For eg in GitHub secrets:

```
STAGING_USERNAME -> <SOME_VALUE>
PROD_USERNAME -> <SOME_VALUE>
```

I want to construct a new variable and set it in GitHub env like below

```
name: Build and Deploy to CAA Backend
on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]
  
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      infraEnv:
        description: 'Env (staging/prod)'     
        required: true
        default: 'staging'
  jobs:
    setup-build-publish:
      name: Test, Build, Deploy, Notify
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      steps:
        name: 
          run: |
            echo "USERNAME=${{secrets.${{github.event.inputs.infraEnv}}_username}}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

But this is throwing a syntax error. How to fix this?

Answer (score 12):

You can do this with the `format` function:

```
${{ secrets[format('{0}_username', github.event.inputs.infraEnv)] }}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer that actually works!! Thanks @mhsmith

Answer (score -2):

You need to write something like

```
   run: |
      echo "USERNAME=${{secrets[github.event.inputs.infraEnv+'_username']}}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

As ${{ }} is a templating function evaluating expressions you cannot nest it.
Instead treat the 'secrets' hash as an hash and construct the key string to achieve
the intended access.

Comment: `+` is not one of the available [GitHub Actions operators](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#operators). You should use `format` instead.