# Nesting an env variable value in another env variable name in Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a matrix which has one axis with has DEPLOY_LOCATIONS as name and some values.

Is it possible to read a credential whose name includes axis value.

For example I have a credential named TEST_X_TOKEN. And I want to read it in each parallel step as ${TEST_{DEPLOY_LOCATIONS}_TOKEN} .

I know the [solution for GitHub actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69450836/nesting-variable-reference-in-github-action-workflows/74116635#74116635) but need for help in Jenkins since I'm a newcomer.

For example I have a credential named TEST_X_TOKEN. And I want to read it in each parallel step as ${TEST_{DEPLOY_LOCATIONS}_TOKEN}.

I am expecting to read credentials for each parallel matrix step that includes the axes value in their name.

Comment: If it's a credential and used by `withCredentials`, you can pass `"TEST_${DEPLOY_LOCATIONS}_TOKEN"` as its name.